# find sub directory with some special parents in different level

Tags: java, algorithm, file, recursion, directory

file system,directory in directory,many level very deep,like a tree.

```
c:\-1
    --2
    ---3
    ----4
    ---6
    ----4
```

Like above,folder parent of "2" is 1,parent of "3" is "2",and so on.
I want to find the folder 4 under 6.

I know the parent of it is 6,and I don`t know the parent of 6,but i know the parent of the parent of "6" is "1",how to writer a method to find the folder I want?

The scene of why i ask is a program generate a folder each time,the tree structure of folder is similar every time,but the name of some sub folder is changed,like the folder "2",may be "2(tom)",not sure.but I need to select the deepest folder by path "1/2/6/4"

i need a common way to implement it.Because some time the path "1/2/6/4" the 6 is not sure,as it change to "6(jim)".And I don`t want to write it like this:

```
for
  for(File f2:f1.listfiles())
     for(File f3:f2.listfiles())
        for
           for
              for
                 for...
```

to deep loop,not readable and hard to change when case is different.

how to writer a method to find the folder "4" I want?I use java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically doing a tree lookup in a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) (Assuming no symlinks in the files hirerchy, if there are such - this is a general graph).

One way to solve the problem, is to do a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), where you search for your target directory. You can pass as an extra parameter to the DFS recursive call<sup>1</sup> a list which include all current "parents", and look in it if the criteria is met.

Pseudo code:

```
Find(root, destination, parents):
  if (root.name == destination and parents satisfies your constraint):
     print(JoinPath(JoinPath(parents), root))
     return true
  for dir in root.ListDirs():
     parents.append(root)
     if (Find(dir, destination, parents)):
       return true
     parents.RemoveLast()
  return false
```

Above pseudo code is easily translated to java

---

(1) assuming you implement a recursive and not iterative DFS.